# Really not getting setResult and onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

Alright, here I am again.  Still learning.  Now I need to pass integer values back and forth from 2 activities.  First activity passes a counter value to the second (which keeps track of player stats).  Second activity has ability to reset stats to zero, hence passing the number back.  But I just can't get my head around it.  Here's what I have so far...

First activity (Main):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Options.class);
            Bundle counters = new Bundle();
            counters.putInt("plWin", plWin);
            counters.putInt("plLoss", plLoss);
            counters.putInt("plDraw", plDraw);
            i.putExtras(counters);
            startActivityForResult(i, ?);
            return true;
```

please fill in the "?"

second activity (Options):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle counters = new Bundle();
    counters.putInt("Wins", wins);
    counters.putInt("Losses", losses);
    counters.putInt("Draws", draws);
    i.putExtras(counters);
    setResult(?, i);
    finish();
}
```

again, can't figure out the "?".

And going back to my first activity, I don't know what goes after:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Dying to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do like this

```
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

For setResult

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

You can use setresult for more advanced sending of results something like

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", "I am done");
setResult(1001, intent);
```

And in onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
   if(requestCode == 100)
   {
    String key = data.getStringExtra("key");
    if(resultcode == 1001 && key!= null && key.equals("I am done"){
       //do something
    }else{
       //do something else
    }

   }
}
```

You dont have to use setResult, if all you need to check is whether you returned from the activity then dont set it and dont check in onActivityResult

Comment: I want to pass integer values back and forth.  come back from second activity, I want to pass the bundle when the back button is pressed

Comment: you can pass an integer to  setResult(int)  and then use it in onActivityResult and get the resultcode

Comment: would that work for multiple integers?  Sorry, still working past the noob stage here.